# Minipage odd format problem

Tags: minipage

I have a matematic LaTex Document, and the only way I can reconstruct the problem is to give you guys a full example. 
https://www.sharelatex.com/project/55f1978b6332182b2e6ca3b8

My problem is that i have created a `minipage` right before end document, but it isn't being displayed probably it should have been formatted so the triangle was on the left and the text to the right, but instead it is showing both minipages on top of each other?

A smaller example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}


\noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[sloped,above] {$Hypotonusen\ c=\num{2.0}$} (B) -- node[right] {Sin(A)} (C) -- node[below] {Cos(A)} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\tkzMarkAngle[fill= gray,size=0.8cm,opacity=.2](C,A,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.6](C,A,B){$30^\circ$}

\end{tikzpicture}



\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth} 
\begin{align*}
\text{cos(vinkel)} &= \frac{\text{hosliggende}}{\text{hypotonuse}} \\
\text{sin(vinkel)} &= \frac{\text{modstående}}{\text{hypotonuse}} \\
\text{tan(vinkel)} &= \frac{\text{modstående}}{\text{hypotonuse}} \\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}


\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have an extraneous \end{document} before the end of the document??

Comment: Year thats on purpose. I just dont wanted the code below to be in the document yet and are saving it for later use.....

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn: That's a well-known techique to drop all parts of a document after some 'point-of-no-return' ;-)

Comment: Sorry, didn't think so I fixed it on Sharelatex. The link is now useless for showing the problem.

Comment: Actually this is a lesson to everyone not to use sharelatex in this way for displaying the problem. Everyone looking at it was seeing a different problem as various people tried to fix it..

Comment: I would like to encourage you to try isolating the problem in the code when posting a question, essentially building a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). This means to  remove parts of the document and preamble until you are left with the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem. The code I added to your question is an example, though it could certainly be reduced even further. With only the ShareLaTeX link the question became nearly worthless for others, as they wont see the problem in the code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your `\end{minipage}`s seem to be in the wrong place. You had

```
\begin{minipage}
<some stuff about sine>

\subsubsection{Sinus}
\begin{minipage}...
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}...
\end{minipage}

\end{minipage}
```

The last `\end{minipage}` should be before the `\subsubsection`.

Other things: Should have thought of this on your previous question that I answered - load the `icomma` package, gives correct spacing when a comma is used as a decimal separator. `\times` or `\cdot` are better for multiplication than `*` I think. Always use `\text{}` for words (like `Hypotenusen`) in math mode.

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn! again tex.stackexchange saved my math project! or should i say tak for hjælpen

Comment: Disagree - with the sharelatex part. It is not a way to have people correct problems here as various people looking at your problem were looking at a different problem.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn Was that directed to me or the OP? If the latter, you should have posted the comment to the question instead of my answer, or at the least pinged him with @. (Don't think he was notified of your comment.)

Comment: Directed at OP certainly. I posted comment under question, but since the thread under your answer proposes sharelatex-based question asking probably appropriate here too.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn Huh? There is no mention of ShareLaTeX anywhere in my answer or the comment to it by the OP - you were the one who brought that in.

Comment: Apologies - yes -- my comments belonged only under the question.